# Jquery replace words that have a prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ask how in jquery how to replace a word that begins only with a `$`, for example:

```
//$example and $friend here means nothing just a regular string
var txt = "This is just an $example my $friend";
```

I want to replace all word in string that begins with `$` will be replace in html tag like this :

```
This is just an <span class="php-var">$example</span> my <span class="php-var">$friend</span>
```

I want do it in client side so I can save my server performance

Comment: This isn't such a heavy task. Does the performance change this much if you do it on the server? I mean, that's how it should be done

Comment: `txt.replace(/\B\$\w+/g, "whatever")` does the trick

Answer (score 3):

Like below:

```
var txt = "This is just an $example my $friend";
var txt = txt.replace(/\$\S+/g,  '<span class="php-var">$&</span>');
```